# How can I add an activation button inside the email that's sent to the user

Tags: android, email

I am currently using  GMailSender to send an activation code to the user to verify his account.

I am thinking of replacing this type of verification by inserting a verification button inside the body of the email.

**How can I insert a button that activates the account inside the body of the email?**

I am not sure if I am using the wrong keywords to search for what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours, I figured it out:

1-Insert the account in the database with a code and an activate field=0.

2-Send a link in the body of the email with that code.

3-activate is set to 1 when the user presses the link to make login with his account.

The answer was easy when I knew stuff that I didn't know.